# Duplicate city in search with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, search, duplicates, city

I'm using google maps into my website, when i search Mira, google maps find me Mira in Portugal, but i want that one in Italy.

How can i do to make as first choice from search the Italian one Mira ?

Comment: I think you can get the city name according to the user's position or set a boundary in advanced.

Comment: g.geocode({'address': addressInput,'region':region,'bounds': bounds, } ....


I set bounds in this way but look like not affected var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(44.4787267,12.0471729),new google.maps.LatLng(44.2211341,12.2102667));